# Check if string ends with given suffix in Rust

Tags: string, rust

What is the Rust equivalent of Go's [`HasSuffix()` function](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasSuffix)?

Comment: Yeah, the ends_with function doesn't show up nicely in Google. I'm betting this question will. Edit: Yep it's already 4th, and by far the most obviously title, so I think it will help some people.

Comment: To be fair, the ___fist___ google search result for _"Rust string ends with"_ links to the rust docs for the [string primitive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html), where the `ends_with` function is easily found if you search for "ends" or "suffix". People need to learn how to search.

Comment: ^ For that reason, I'm close-voting this as a request for an off-site resource. I'm not saying it's a bad question, just that people are better off being linked to the documentation.

Comment: @Cerbrus: there is *no resource request in this question*. You are stretching the close option way past the intended use here.

Comment: I cannot see any words about requesting off-site resource here, even provided that the answers can be found outside the site, to be fair we can just only assume it is not requesting off-site resource

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It turns out there is [`str::ends_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.ends_with). For some reason, code completion didn't find it for me.

Comment: Note that code completion for Rust is not very mature at the moment